# Syntax highlighting for non-project files in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, syntax-highlighting

I have a simple C# project which loads external C# files at startup to be used as scripts. Unfortunately when editing any of these 'non-project' files in Visual Studio I only get the most basic of syntax highlighting, since classes and types within the project are not known in the context of this external file.

Without adding the files to my project (defeating the purpose of them being external scripts), is there any way I can define an external interface or somehow otherwise convince Visual Studio (2008) to parse the code within these files in the context of the classes in the project?

A couple of clarifications (with thanks to the early answerers)

- People should be able to edit these scripts without access to my source code
- People shouldn't have to set up an entire Visual Studio project to edit one source file that's likely to contain less that 10 lines of actual code.

Comment: When you say basic syntax highlighting, what do you mean exactly? Is it not recognizing certain objects because the classes are in a non-referenced namespace?

Comment: @JasonDown Yeah it is not recognising the classes that are part of the project because the script files live elsewhere.

Comment: The [tag:script] tag is meaningless here: it has nothing to do with the actual question that is being asked, and it is unlikely that anyone who follows or searches the [tag:script] tag will be able to answer this question. And note that phrases like "thank you" in questions are [considered noise and should be removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). A script runs to do this *automatically*, but it looks like it missed yours. Please do not roll back my edits. If you have concerns, open a question on Meta.

Comment: Fine, if *in your opinion* a small code file is not called a script, and simple politeness is considered noise, then so be it.

Comment: Look I've just checked the Meta question about noise as well as some of the posts in the 'script' topic. I now know that simply writing 'Thanks' at the end of the post is NOT considered noise, and that the 'script' tag covers things from Javascript to Bashscript to MATLAB.  I'm sorry, but I disagree on both of these points. So how about you edit your own posts, and if *you* have an issue with someone's post, *you* raise *your* question on Meta. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You will always need a reference to these classes.  Maybe you can add these files as a link to the project or to a new project with a reference.

Comment: No, as I said that would completely defeat the purpose of enumerating scripts at runtime. If I decided to do that there would be no need to compile them at runtime at all, I'd simply compile them into the project.

Comment: Just to clarify, the idea is that people can develop these scripts without having access to my code. ;-)

Comment: I understand now. I think you have to do your own syntax highlighting then. Maybe use an existing component where you can define keywords...

Answer (score 0):

Visualstudio needs some informations to accomplish that.

I would think about the Bridge Pattern and you need to add the class body in the same file

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern

or using mock objects- you can easily use them to provide syntax highlighting without sharing your code (the same here - all in one file):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object

You can separate the script and the assiting classes if you would allow having a project file.